# Day wise aggregation considering client's timezone from millions of rows

Tags: mysql, bigdata, web-analytics

Suppose I've a table where visitors'(website visitor) information is stored. Suppose, the table structure consists of the following fields:

> 1. ID
> 2. visitor_id
> 3. visit_time (stored as milliseconds in UTC since 
>          '1970-01-01 00:00:00')

Millions of rows are in this table and it's still growing.

In that case, If I want to see a report **(day vs visitors)** from any timezone then one solution is :

**Solution #1:**

1. Get the timezone of the report viewer (i.e. client)
2. Aggregate the data from this table considering the client's timezone
3. Show the result day wise

But In that case performance will degrade. Another solution may be the following:

**Solution #2:**

- Using Pre-aggregated tables / summary tables where client's timezone is ignored

But in either case there is a `trade off between performance and correctness`.

**Solution #1** ensures correctness and **Solution #2** ensures better performance.

I want to know what is the best practice in this particular scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The issue of handling time comes up a fair amount when you get into distributed systems, users and matching events between various sources of data.

I would strongly suggest that you ensure all logging systems use UTC. This allows collection from any variety of servers (which are all hopefully kept synchronized with respect to their view of the current UTC time) located anywhere in the world.

Then, as requests come in, you can convert from the users timezone to UTC. At this point you have the same decision -- perform a real-time query or perhaps access some data previously summarized.

Whether or not you want to aggregate the data in advance will depend on a bunch of things. Some of these might entail the ability to reduce the amount of data kept, reducing the amount of processing to support queries, how often queries will be performed or even the cost of building a system versus the amount of use it might see.

With respect to best practices -- keep the display characteristics (e.g. time zone) independent from the processing of the data.

If you haven't already, be sure you consider the lifetime of the data you are keeping. Will you need ten years of back data available? Hopefully not. Do you have a strategy for culling old data when it is no longer required? Do you know how much data you'll have if you store every record (estimate with various traffic growth rates)?

Again, a best practice for larger data sets is to understand how you are going to deal with the size and how you are going to manage that data over time as it ages. This might involve long term storage, deletion, or perhaps reduction to summarized form.

Oh, and to slip in a Matrix analogy, what is really going to bake your noodle in terms of "correctness" is the fact that correctness is not at issue here. Every timezone has a different view of traffic during a "day" in their own zone and every one of them is "correct". Even those oddball time zones that differ from yours by an adjustment that isn't measured only in hours.